# How can i decode my html entities chars (ÆØÅ)?

Tags: php

```
$test = "selvf&oslash;lgelig";
$test = html_entity_decode($test);
```

I want this to output "selvfølgelig", but this turns out as selvf�lgelig

How can i make this output like i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$string="selvf&oslash;lgelig";
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

i think you dont need to actually use this function. 
EDIT: you can use the 
    < meta >
 tag that Qualcuno provided instead of throwing a header.

Answer (score 2):

It's an encoding issue, not related to html_entity_decode.
Make sure your page is in UTF-8: put this tag in your `<head></head>` section of the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Set, then, the third parameter of html_entity_decode(), `charset`, to `'UTF-8'` (the default value).

PS: Please note that setting the encoding of the page to UTF-8 will solve many issues, but may introduce others, since UTF-8 can use multibyte characters. There may be security issues too, if you fail to validate input data correctly.

Comment: +1, although it is worth noting that if you are working with XHTML you can put an `<?xml ... ?>` declaration at the top of the file which does the same job, and could probably be considered to be more correct in these circumstances. E.g. `<?xml version='2.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
html_entity_decode($test, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

There are [other charsets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) too:

```
html_entity_decode($test, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

You need to define with which charset you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the third parameter of html_entity_decode to specify a character set.

```
$test = html_entity_decode($test, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: 'utf-8' is the default value, so it can't be the issue. Instead, he has to set the meta charset to UTF-8, or return an header as omasdg suggests.