# PHP explode converts ÆØÅ to &

Tags: php, explode

I have written a script that converts a users full name to "First name + first initial of last name". But when the users last name starts with either "ÆØ" or "Å" the script converts these characters to "&". Ex. "Barbara Østergaard" returns "Barbara &.".

```
if (empty($user->first_name) && empty($user->last_name)) { 
  $full_name = "Anonymous teacher";
  $url = "anonymous-teacher";  
} else { 
  $name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name; 
  $name = explode(" ", $name); 
  $full_name = $name[0]." ".$name[1][0].".";
  $url = strtolower($name[0]."-".$name[1][0]);
}
```

Comment: So, you want to skip special character for first letter of last name?

Comment: It should just return "Barbara Ø." for "Barbara Østergaard" and not "Barbara &.".

Comment: does $name[1] return correctly in the first place? if yes then $name[1][0] may be the problem

Comment: `$name[1][0]` is only a byte (`&` or `38` in dec). But `Ø` is a multibyte char.

Comment: How would you solve it @Federico? It seems like its only $name[1][0] that is the problem.

Comment: You should use `mb_substr` like @Satisfaction suggest in his answer. But I don't think that you're using utf-8. What's the encoding of your `$user->last_name` string?

Comment: Great after using "html_entity_decode" on the last name and then using mb_substr i got it working. Thank you so much.

Comment: What if firstname contains a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using UTF-8 characters, parsing the characters like an array won't work properly.

This should solve your problem and return the first character of the second word:

```
mb_substr( $name[1], 0, 1,'UTF8');
```

Working example:

```
   $name = "Barbara Østergaard";
   $name = explode(" ", $name); 
   echo $name[0]." ".mb_substr( $name[1], 0, 1,'UTF8');.".";
```

Comment: It still returns "&" instead of "Ø".

Comment: `UTF8` is for mysql,  you mean `UTF-8` :P

Comment: @Federico both should work, really!


Mikkel, are you sure you're doing everything correctly? Check my updated, I tested it and it seems to work. Check if your file is encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score -2):

Use html_entity_decode() on the names

Example: [How can i decode my html entities chars (ÆØÅ)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309693/how-can-i-decode-my-html-entities-chars-%C3%86%C3%98%C3%85)

Comment: Still the same, sorry.